# Create WCF service at runtime

Tags: sql-server, wcf

I’ve created WCF service that connects between a windows 8 app and SQL Server. But now the connection is to be made at runtime, like where the server name is a user input. I wanted to know do we keep adding multiple service references for every connection made to a database? But how do I make these WCF connections at runtime? Or do we have to use variables in the connection string? But then how do I link this variable to the Service.svc.cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it can be achieved by using the `ClientBase` of System.ServiceModel. Please go through this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1525489.aspx/1)